# My spyder kernel is keep restarting. plot.show() raising an error

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to run a code using spyder. plot.show() raising an error. while running plot.show() my kernel is automatically restarting.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Maybe this is related with this issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659

Something you could try is to downgrade `freetype`: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659#issuecomment-961306197